# How to create a new plist in iphone

Tags: iphone, plist

Good Morning
How to create a new plist in iphone? it is possible
please any one help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: good morning? haha damn! its 8:32 at night in california!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create Property list file by right click on project file, choose new file and select resources like this -

[image]

[image]

You can also create a Property list file through code like this -

to create a new file -

```
#define FilePath                [@"~/Documents/Demo.plist" stringByStandardizingPath]

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1,obj2,obj3,nil];
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:array  format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0  errorDescription:nil];
[data writeToFile:FilePath atomically:YES];
```

To read that plist file -

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:FilePath];
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSArray *array = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:nil];

obj1 = [array objectAtIndex:0];
obj2 = [array objectAtIndex:1];
obj3 = [array objectAtIndex:2];
```

Comment: if an answer helps you then you should accept it so that it can be helpful for other users also.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode,

Right click -> new File  -> Resource tab -> Property List File.

Answer (score -2):

The wise man once said:
    To know an answer, we must first know the question.

Read [this.](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-create-an-iphone-preferences-file) Hopefully, It's what you're looking for.

EDIT: by wise man, I meant myself.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.